# Convert nautical miles to degrees longitude given a latitude using Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

I want to explicitly define a Google maps [LatLngBounds](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds) object to be x nautical miles to the right of a [LatLong](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng) P and x nautical miles left of P.  And define the LatLngBounds to be y nautical miles above the point P and y nm below P.

So basically I want to define a LatLngBounds using latitude and longitude, and I want to get that latitude and longitude from x, y, and P.

Degrees latitude converts to degrees longitude easily: 1 degree equals one nautical mile.  But
degrees longitude per nm changes with latitude.  The formula is (in php)

```
public static function degPerNmAtLat($lat) {
    $pi80 = M_PI / 180;
    $lat = $lat*$pi80; //convert lat to radians
    $p1 = 111412.84;        // longitude calculation term 1
    $p2 = -93.5;            // longitude calculation term 2
    $p3 = 0.118;            // longitude calculation term 3
    // below: calculate the length of a degree of latitude and longitude in meters
    $longlen = ($p1 * cos($lat)) + ($p2 * cos(3 * $lat)) +  ($p3 * cos(5 * $lat));
    $longlen = $longlen * (3.280833333) / (5280 * 1.15077945);  // convert to nautical miles
    return 1/$longlen;
}
```

But this seems like a common task, and I wonder if Google maps has a function I am missing which would accomplish this.  Is there a native Google maps way to create my LatLngBounds object from x, y, and P without using the formula above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [computeOffset()](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#spherical) function in the [Google Maps API V3 geometry library](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry.html):

```
var dist = nauticalMiles * 1852; // convert nm to meters
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
var eastPoint = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(point,dist,90.0);
var westPoint = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(point,dist,270.0);
```

Comment: Yes, this is it.  The spherical object in the namespace object has several other useful methods too, such as distance between two LatLng objects and heading.  Thanks.